# Apple Developer Program expiring before prospective app launch

Tags: iphone-developer-program

A simple question that requires an immediate answer. My developer program (for ios) is going to expire in a few days time. I still have 2 Incident supports left from apple.

My questions are

1) I am going to release one more app in a few days time and generally it takes week or two to get approval. If my developer program gets over before the approval; will it gets published?? assuming that its free from bugs.

2) if not what can I do ? want to use the incident anyways.

ps: I will not be able to join the program for some time since I do not have money left.

appreciate your time. thanks

Comment: If you are in need of an immediate answer you might want to contact apple or look for this information on their site.

Answer (score 0):

If your developer program expires, your app will not be available for download (see https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/).

If you want to sell apps via the app store then you will have to wait until you renew your developer program.

Comment: thanks for the excellent information and the appropriate edit. Its so better than apple developer support. One more question. If i renew my membership before it expires, will my TSI gets carry forwarded? ? i means 2 + 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to question 2 so reposting it so that it may be useful to others searching the same.

If i renew my membership before it expires, will my TSI gets carry forwarded? ? i means 2 + 2 ?

Apple Developer Program and Apple Developer Enterprise Program
Included with each enrollment are two Technical Support Incidents, which will expire at the end of your membership year. You will receive two new TSIs when you renew your membership.

more information here: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/